# PHP file_get_contents() is not working on PLESK / CENTOS7 Server

Tags: php, centos, plesk

I was using cpanel before, but I'm using Plesk Panel / Centos7 now. I moved my sites to Plesk Panel from CPanel. I'm runing file_get_contents() function, but it's not working on Plesk Panel.

Why? I dont know why. What should i do?

my code;

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

this code is not working on Plesk Panel.

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? if not try to check the logs, also edit your question and post the error here.

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error, just null screen.

Answer (score 0):

What is error message says?
if error message says, the stream (URL) requested cannot be opened. There are many possible reasons for this:
1. base URL is bad. $pc['pcname']
2. username and/or password are bad
3. username/password do not have permission on the server
4. Your system cannot reach the server (firewall, PHP permissions, ...)

I would use the following strategy to debug:
1. Dump $url and write it down.
2. Use a browser with debug tools (eg Firefox/Firebug) and try to access that URL.
3. Look at the headers returned to see what error the server reports (if any).
4. Think about why that error is returned